# Narrowing displayed content by checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filter

I am looking to modify this code so that the results displayed have the values of all checkboxes. For instance, by checking "computers" and "video-games" I would only have result 3.

How would I make this change?

```
<div class="tags">
<label><input type="checkbox" rel="arts" /> Arts </label>
<label><input type="checkbox" rel="computers" /> Computers </label>
<label><input type="checkbox" rel="health" /> Health </label>
<label><input type="checkbox" rel="video-games" /> Video Games </label>
</div>

<ul class="results">
<li class="arts computers">
    Result 1
</li>
<li class="video-games">
    Result 2
</li>
<li class="computers health video-games">
    Result 3
</li>
<li class="arts video-games">
    Result 4
</li>
</ul>

$('div.tags').delegate('input:checkbox', 'change', function()
{
 var $lis = $('.results > li').hide();
 //For each one checked
 var numChecked = $('input:checked').each(function()
 {
      $lis.filter('.' + $(this).attr('rel')).show();
 }).length;

if (!numChecked) $lis.show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gZUrA/2/

Comment: I've changed your [tag:java] tag to a [tag:javascript] tag. Please understand that these are two completely different programming languages, about as closely related as ham and hamburger are, and that if you mis-tag your question, you will not get the right experts in to review it, and this will hurt your chances of getting decent help. Since I know nothing about Javascript, this is about all that I can do for you except to wish you well and hope that you get a decent answer soon.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I blame it on carelessness rather than ignorance.

Comment: I'm not sure about your code, but just an FYI if you didn't know, there's a framework called AngularJS which is meant to do things like this. It has somewhat of a learning curve, but is powerful once you know it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get an array of the checked names and use it to create a selector for the call to `.filter()`.

```
$('div.tags').delegate('input:checkbox', 'change', function() {
    var checkedNames = $('div.tags input:checkbox:checked').map(function() { return $(this).attr('rel'); }).get();

    if (checkedNames.length > 0) {
        var selector = '.' + checkedNames.join('.');
        $('.results > li').hide().filter(selector).show();
    } else {
        $('.results > li').show()
    }
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S8hv5/1/)